# Writing data from HTML page to text (.txt) file

Tags: java

I am a newbie to Java and kinda struggling with ideas on how to do this task with minimal coding and efficiently.

I have a HTML page with multiple **tables** and **headings** in it

Now my task is to export the data from this page to a text file with the corresponding **headings** lined up properly and **tables** in column format.

Is there a easy way of doing this by using some libraries?

I want to start by 1st creating a text (Sample_Text_001.txt) file in a specified  (C;\users\kventure\testFiles) directory and if that file already exists, then delete it and create a new one.

Comment: Do you want to copy the HTML markups or the parsed HTML?

Comment: what do you mean by "I have a page"? Is it an html file inside your project? A jsp? A random page on the web? An html page you downloaded?

Comment: It's a JSP file. I don't want any HTML or CSS elements in the text file. Only Data thats populated in page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [JSoup Library](http://jsoup.org/). It's an HTML parser library that can be used to read contents of html pages.